# MySQL how to get values from three table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables and i want to select sum of rs from table credit and deposit group by acno. Following is my query:

```
select a.amname,sum(d.rs),sum(c.rs),a.acno 
from deposit d,account a,credit c 
where
a.acno=d.acno && a.acno=c.acno 
&& d.date1 between '$date1' and '$date2'
&& c.date1 between '$date1' and '$date2' 
&& a.scode='3' 
group by d.acno,c.acno;
```

Comment: Whats the question,or the error,or the problem?

Comment: I want sum of column rs from table deposit and sum of column rs from table credit which have same acno within single query.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is with GROUP BY.

Try this

```
      select a.amname,sum(d.rs),sum(c.rs),a.acno 
      from deposit d
      INNER JOIN account a ON a.acno=d.acno 
      INNER JOIN credit c  ON a.acno=c.acno
      where  d.date1 between '$date1' and '$date2'
      and c.date1 between '$date1' and '$date2' 
      and  a.scode='3' 
      group by a.amname,c.acno
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to 'group by' the credit and deposit tables separately, then include the results together. It would probably look like this:

```
select a.acno, a.amname, c.sumRS, d.sumRS 
from account a
INNER JOIN  (select acno, SUM(rs) as sumRS from credit where date1 between '$date1' and '$date2' group by acno) c ON a.acno=c.acno 
INNER JOIN (select acno, SUM(rs) as sumRS from deposit where date1 between '$date1' and '$date2' group by acno) d ON a.acno=d.acno
where a.scode='3';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use union. I don't know your schema, so it is a speculation of a working request

```
select sum(rs), acno from
(
    select sum(rs),acno 
    from deposit
    where date1 between '$date1' and '$date2'
    and scode='3' 
    group by acno
  union
    select sum(rs),acno 
    from account
    where date1 between '$date1' and '$date2' 
    group by acno
  union
    select sum(rs),acno 
    from credit
    where date1 between '$date1' and '$date2'
    group by acno
)
group by acno
```

Comment: I said that this request is an idea because I don't know your datamodel. But you should easily adapt the query for your need.